# Does energy get attracted by gravity?

Tags: energy, gravity

I will describe my question using a scenario since I don't know exactly what to ask that will convey my question properly.

Let's say two identical faces were to get punched by a fist that generates the exact same amount of energy, 1000 joules. (same fist size, same impact point). The only difference being one of the faces is on earth, and the other is on a planet with much much higher gravity.

Once the fist has already hit the face and the energy has been transferred to the face, would gravity make a difference on that transferred energy? Assuming everything was identical up until the impact on faces, would gravity make a difference on how much damage each face takes? Would the face on the higher gravity planet take less damage, or would it be the exact same?

If gravity won't have any impact in this scenario, why not? Doesn't energy have mass and therefore affected by gravity?

Comment: Sorry for my first comment! Energy is just as well affected as mass. Light is bend. If you get hotter you weigh more.

Comment: But would the kinetic energy be affected AFTER the impact has happened though? I got another user saying gravity wouldn't have any effect on the transferred (after impact) kinetic energy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would the force transferred from a punch get affected by gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711675/)

Comment: Please don't post what is essentially a duplicate of a previously-closed question.  Instead, you can edit your original post (which was closed due to lacking clarity) to add explanations that provide clarity on what you are actually asking.  Then you can ask to re-open the original question.

Comment: I edited the previous question and copy pasted this because last one was closed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/703853/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The energy wont be affected. If you hit someone here or somewhere there, the energy given will be the same. But the weight (mg) increase is different in both cases. Or do I get you wrong?